# Generate combinations from lists inside a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-itertools

I have a list with lists which has cominations like `baselist = [['Store3', 'Store4', 'Store5'], ['Rack1', 'Rack2'], ['Box1', 'Box2']]` and try to generate a list with Strings like:

```
Store3Rack1Box1
Store3Rack1Box2
Store3Rack2Box1
Store3Rack2Box2
Store4Rack1Box1
Store4Rack1Box2
Store4Rack2Box1
Store4Rack2Box2
```

I've tried it with [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/itertools.html) and [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html). But in the end I have no idea how to solve this. What's the right way to a solution?

Comment: Maybe show what exactly you have tried? `itertools` does sound like the right idea.

Comment: `map(''.join, product(*baselist))` if you need a generator, or `(''.join(l) for l in product(*baselist))` if a generator expression is easier to read for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`itertools.product` is exactly the way to go. Did you try unpacking the list before passing it to the function?

```
In [523]: print('\n'.join(map(''.join, itertools.product(*baselist))))
Store3Rack1Box1
Store3Rack1Box2
Store3Rack2Box1
Store3Rack2Box2
Store4Rack1Box1
Store4Rack1Box2
...
```

Let me break it down:

1. `itertools.product(*baselist)` generates combinations in the form of a list of tuples
2. `map(''.join, ...)` joins each product list together
3. `'\n'.join(...)` will ready your output for printing

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thanks, exactly what I was searching for. I was very close to it, I didn't unpack and join it.

Answer (score 1):

```
map("".join,itertools.product(*baselist))
```

Comment: You better explain your explanation than just posting some anonymous code section. You should read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)